# directive to directive communication using broadcast angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angularjs-events

I have two directives and need to pass value from one directive after a post request into another directive.

The first directive looks like

```
var fileUpload = angular.module('fileUploadDirective',[]);
fileUpload.directive('fileUpload', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/fileUpload/file-upload.tpl.html',
            controller: fileUploadCtrl
        }
    });
fileUploadCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http','FileUploader'];
function fileUploadCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http, FileUploader) {

    var vm =this
    vm.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item) {            
        $rootScope.$broadcast("NEW_EVENT",data); //send event
    }
}
```

The second directive looks like

```
var resultPage = angular.module('resultPageDirective',[]);
resultPage.directive('resultDirective',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attributes){
        },
        controller: function($scope,$rootScope,$attrs,$http){    
            $scope.junkFiles = ["abc","xyz"];
            $scope.$on("NEW_EVENT",function(event,data){ //listen to event
                   console.log(data);
            });

        },
        templateUrl: 'app/views/resultPage/resultPage.tpl.html'
    }
});
```

The second directive event is not listened

Comment: So what is the problem or question? Might be a good time to review [ask]

Comment: second directive event is not working. Cannot listen

Comment: Well there's a syntax error in the second directive (missing closing braces), but maybe you've edited the code incorrectly before posting? Otherwise you'd have an error in the console and the directive wouldn't compile. Have you tried listening on $rootScope? It *should* work on $scope, but I've sometimes had issues with that.

Comment: sorry i edited it with the bracket. I have but still doesnt work

Comment: these two controllers aren't even in the same module.  they don't share a `$rootScope`.

Comment: so how do i share them ?

Comment: either declare both of these controllers in the same module, or create a service to hold the shared data and don't use `$broadcast` at all.

Answer (score 0):

For event listening of $scope, you should use `$on` instead of `on`

```
$scope.$on("NEW_EVENT",function(event,data){ //listen to event
       console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Hi did you get an 'vm' undefined error in your first directive's controller? That is not `controllerAs` supposed to be used i think. At least you need `var vm = this`

Comment: I saw you are putting these two directives in two separate modules. Are you using them in one big module? Like `angular.module("app",["fileUploadDirective","resultPageDirective"])` ?